# can't run "glxgears" in root on lxc 2.0 container

Tags: 16.04, lxc

I am running lxc2.0 container(privileged) on Ubuntu 16.0.4LTS 32-bit.

Inside the container I installed `mesa-utils` that has the `glxgears` app.

my container config file `/var/lib/lxc/mk7i_container/config` is:

```
 Template used to create this container: /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-download
# Parameters passed to the template: --no-validate
# For additional config options, please look at lxc.container.conf(5)

# Uncomment the following line to support nesting containers:
#lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/nesting.conf
# (Be aware this has security implications)


# Distribution configuration
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/ubuntu.common.conf
lxc.arch = x86

lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:1 rwm

lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 130:* rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 124:* rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 122:* rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 123:* rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 126:* rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 127:0 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 120:0 rwm

# Container specific configuration
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/mk7i_container/rootfs
lxc.rootfs.backend = dir
lxc.utsname = mk7i_container

# Network configuration
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:c8:fd:1e

#mounts for XServer DISPLAY
lxc.mount.entry = /dev/dri dev/dri none bind,optional,create=dir
lxc.mount.entry = /tmp/.X11-unix tmp/.X11-unix none bind,optional,create=dir
lxc.mount.entry = /dev/video0 dev/video0 none bind,optional,create=file
```

To log in into the container as user 'Ubuntu', I am using the following command:

```
sudo lxc-console -n mk7i_container
```

After login, I set the `DISPLAY` env variable as:

```
export DISPLAY=":0.0"
```

And run `glxgears` and it runs fine. I can see the Xwindow with gears moving in it.

However, after that I enter root mode via `sudo su` command.
And try to run glxgears, but I get the following error:

```
No protocol specified
Error: couldn't open display :0.0
```

Not sure why this error is coming. If user `ubuntu` runs x apps fine , I expected root to do the same.

Anyone know what's wrong here ?

Comment: Is this related to x-forwarding? Like logging into a server remotely? If so, could you please take a look at my question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028231/error-could-not-initialize-gl-extensions-despite-having-opengl-libraries-i) and see if your answer could partially or completely answer my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it and run `glxgears` in root mode.
The problem was with the xauth.

The host system already had `xauth`.The idea is to use the key of the already trusted user, which in my case was `manik` on the host system.

Using command `xauth list` gave me the following output:

```
manik/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  a4f6256398303725763c5595f404afbb
```

I am going to use the key in hex(right most entry above) in my root user account inside container.

I installed xauth package in the container:

```
sudo apt-get install xauth
```

Inside `root` user prompt in container:

```
export DISPLAY=":0"
xauth add $DISPLAY . a4f6256398303725763c5595f404afbb
```

And now `glxgears` works fine in root mode.